# Overlap Subreports SSRS

Tags: reporting, reporting-services-2016

I was trying to create one report with several pages doing this:

- I've created like 3 reports with different embedded datasets (each report has nothing to do with the others).
- I've created a main report where i put the 3 subreports, overlaying them.
- In SSRS web view i can change the the pages in order to see each subreport in a different page.

The problem is when i tried to export the report in PDF, there is not a "page break" so the first page contain all the reports overlayed.... this is a big issue....

Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can enclose sub reports in a rectangle and provide page break properties to the rectangle.
1st sub-report should be within 1st rectangle and as is.
You can also make sure, sub-reports are one-by-one in the design for proper page breaks.